# How to set in CSS in grid this disposition in picture?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.grid-item .item1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item item1"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item"> </div>
</div>
```

I have this, but it's not what I want
[What I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0ZZx.png)

I want this, see this following picture :

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Pig.png)

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.

So you setting height of `grid-item` is wrong, because it defeats the whole purpose of grid, which is to assign area to grid childrens based upon the layout divided by grid-lines.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  height:200px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  
}
.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item item1"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the grid-items and set the rows to be 100px.

Then tell the "tall" item to be in column 2

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
}

.grid-item.item1 {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item item1"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, You have a typo  `.grid-item .item1` , `.item1` is not a child of `.grid-item` . You need to remove that space in between classnames : `.grid-item.item1`.

beside you have also to reset height for `.item1` so it can grow the entire rows it spans, and  if you also set in which columns it should stand, it avoids to see it elsewhere.

To help you debug your css, give different `background-color` to your items to see exactly where they stand.

possible CSS fix

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.grid-item.item1 {
  grid-row-start:1;
  grid-row-end:3;
  grid-column:2;
  height:auto;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item item1"> </div>

  <div class="grid-item"> </div>
</div>
```